# Reduce: number of available solutions changes and I want to pick the lowest

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, conditional

I have an equation that has no analytical solution and can have multiple roots. I am focusing on Real roots that are in the (0,1) interval. For example:

```
Block[{A = 0.3, B = 1}, 
 Reduce[1/(16 (1 - x)^7) + (
     4.5 (1 - x) (-1 + 3 x))/(-B - 0.5 A + 4.5 (1 - x)^2 x)^3 == 0 && 
   0 < x < 1, x, Reals]]
```

For some values of A and B, I may have:

- no root that satisfies my constraints
- 1 root
- 2 roots

I would like to always pick up, when it exists, the lowest root. Otherwise, I would like to set `x=1'.

I have tried two different things: Select+ Conditional; creating a table and picking up the lowest+Conditional. I have failed in both. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Reduce` returns an `Or` expression, you can apply `Sort` to get the lowest, something like this:

```
With[{A = 3/10, B = 1},
 Block[{s},
  s = Reduce[1/(16 (1 - x)^7) + (4.5 (1 - x) (-1 + 3 x))/
        (-B - 0.5 A + 4.5 (1 - x)^2 x)^3 == 0 &&
     0 < x < 1, x, 
    Reals];
  If[Head[s] === Or, First[Sort[s]], s]
  ]
 ]

(*  x == 0.349826  *)
```

Try it with {A,B}={-1,0} for the single solution case, and {A,B}={-1,2} for the no solution case.

**Sanity Check:**
The following code will perform a quick sanity check to confirm that `Sort` will give us the right answers:

```
nTest = 20;
testCases = Thread[x == RandomReal[{0, 1}, nTest]]
Sort[testCases]
```

Exercising the above code over various ranges like {0,1}, {-1,1} and {-100,100} indicates `Sort` is doing its job, as long as the expressions are all of the assumed form.  To get the least of the expressions, we apply `First` to the sorted list.  To get the greatest of the expressions, we apply `Last`.

**Why `Greater` did not work:**  A comment mentioned that `Sort[s,Greater]` did not work to return the highest answer. 
So, why didn't `Greater` work?  The documentation for [`Greater`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Greater.html) says it returns True or False for real numbers.  We are trying to sort expressions.  Since `Greater[x==1, x==2]` does not return True or False, we are not really comparing the expressions.

**How to use `Greater`**
Since `Greater` works with real numbers, we can simply point to the real numbers in our expressions, like this:

```
Sort[testCases, Greater[Last[#1], Last[#2]] &]
```

Here, we are applying `Last` to expressions like `x == 3.14159`, so `Last` returns just the real number.  We pass 2 real numbers to `Greater`, and voilà, `Greater` makes the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @LouisB. I am not sure if `Sort` is indeed working. If I try to get the highest number by doing `If[Head[s] === Or, First[Sort[s, Greater]], s]` it doesn't change anything. So I am not sure if Mathematica is sorting the values or the name of the variable that is being solved to be honest.

Comment: @LauraK  You are right to be skeptical.  It would be wise to examine the output of `Reduce` to make sure it has the assumed form.  I added some ideas on testing `Sort` alone and using `Sort` with `Greater`.

Comment: Your comments are great. Very good information you have added there. Your answer actually gave me a good idea: to use `ToRules`. I have mentioned below in case that is of any use to you. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

LouisB's help gave me a good idea on how to proceed. I could first transform `Reduce`'s results into a sequence and then select the answers and `Order` them.

To select the lowest solution:

```
s=Block[{A = 0.3, B = 1}, 
 Reduce[1/(16 (1 - x)^7) + (
     4.5 (1 - x) (-1 + 3 x))/(-B - 0.5 A + 4.5 (1 - x)^2 x)^3 == 0 && 
   0 < x < 1, x, Reals]]
ss={ToRules[s]}
First[Sort[ss[[All, 1, 2]]]]
```

To select the highest solution:

```
s=Block[{A = 0.3, B = 1}, 
 Reduce[1/(16 (1 - x)^7) + (
     4.5 (1 - x) (-1 + 3 x))/(-B - 0.5 A + 4.5 (1 - x)^2 x)^3 == 0 && 
   0 < x < 1, x, Reals]]
ss={ToRules[s]}
First[Sort[ss[[All, 1, 2]], Greater]]
```

I hope someone can benefit from this answer that was inspired by LouisB's help from above.